# Use QEMU user emulation to run SPEC2017

Tags: qemu

I am trying to run SPEC2017 program using QEMU user emulation. Running integer speed cases works fine. However, some float speed cases can't run successfully.

It looks like the default memory size is not enough to run the cases. **How can I set the memory space in QEMU user Emulation?**

This is my command:

```
./qemu-riscv64 ./cam4_s_base.rv64-m64
```

This is the error screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with ARM. I don't think that you can change it without rebuilding the QEMU binary.

For ARM, I changed the file arm-compat-semi.c (commit: `d0f4aa7d`):

```
diff --git a/semihosting/arm-compat-semi.c b/semihosting/arm-compat-semi.c
index 329ea11260..479953130d 100644
--- a/semihosting/arm-compat-semi.c
+++ b/semihosting/arm-compat-semi.c
@@ -44,7 +44,7 @@
 #ifdef CONFIG_USER_ONLY
 #include "qemu.h"

-#define COMMON_SEMI_HEAP_SIZE (128 * 1024 * 1024)
+#define COMMON_SEMI_HEAP_SIZE (256 * 1024 * 1024)
 #else
 #include "qemu/cutils.h"
```

To increase the heap size by 128MB.

This comment from the top of the same file suggests that it might apply to your case as well?

```
Adapted for systems other than ARM, including RISC-V, by Keith Packard
```